# error: ‘calcOpticalFlowPyrLK’ is not a member of ‘cv’ - OpenCV 2.4.2

Tags: c++, opencv, g++, ubuntu-11.10

I'm having this error on OpenCV 2.4.2 about this.

I'm using this line of code:

```
 cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prev, next, prev_pts, next_pts, status, error);
```

And on compile time it shows this error:

```
testopticalflow.cpp:75:4: error: ‘calcOpticalFlowPyrLK’ is not a member of ‘cv’
```

This is the result if I use pkg-config

```
pkg-config opencv --libs
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so
```

Sorry I'm still a newbie when it comes to Linux environment so I have no idea where I went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, stupid mistake.
I forgot to add this as header:

```
#include <opencv2/video/tracking.hpp>
```

Comment: Thats OK! but where to add??

Comment: @Kamalakar the header? Along with the other header, I suppose.